# What is this 18-word seed of random letters?

Tags: wallet-recovery

I have a seed from a few years ago that looks like this:

**this is not the actual seed, but it's random letters just like this:**

```
nasd oasi lksn oifd nwee ckvj osdi pwer asem
pasd werw nase nwqe noas pmrr nolv psme ksdw
```

How can I recover the wallet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for Luke Childs' [BIP39 recovery tool](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/pull/6219), which has now been merged into Electrum. It scans common derivation paths for common seed configurations, in search for previously used addresses and balance.

You can run it offline on your own machine (as you should!), just ensure that the Electrum wallet you download is not compromised.

You can download the Electrum desktop app for most OSs (+ signatures) [here](https://electrum.org/#home)

Answer (score 2):

It's an armory backup seed. See https://www.bitcoinarmory.com/. It's a wallet that requires bitcoin core full node so you'll need that as well.